# Is there a way to use Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap on AppCode?

Tags: intellij-idea, appcode

Im just wondering, is there any way to import "Mac OS X 10.5+" keymap (don't get confused with just "Mac OS X 10.5" keymap) in AppCode?

Keymap named "XCode" is similar one, but not the same. So is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA's "Mac OS X 10.5+" is the Default keymap in AppCode.